# Get the selected option/value of a dynamic select field in RAILS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have here a `select_field` with a dynamic ID.

Why dynamic? Because I used a nested field/form.

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |c| [c.code, c.id] }, {prompt:""},{class:"cat-code"} %>
```

I have here a JS code that simply gets the dynamic id per select field.

```
        <%= javascript_tag do %>
                $(function() {



                    $(".cat-code").change(function(){          

                        var getID = this.id;
                        var value =  $("getID").val()

                        alert(value);

                        if (value == "1"){
                            $(".div1").show();
                            $(".div2").hide();
                        }

                        else if (value == "2"){
                            $(".div1").hide();
                            $(".div2").show();
                        }

                    });


                });
        <% end %>
```

I can get the id using..

```
alert(getID);
```

But getting the selected value turns `undefined` which results the `show()` and `hide()` divs for not working too.

Any workarounds will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var value =  $("#" + getID).val()
```

Comment: Thank you will accept your answer too (after 7 mins  according to stack). However I already solved this one with another workaround. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $(this);
var value = element.val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, already solved this using.

```
                $(".cat-code").change(function(){          

                    var getID = this.id;
                    var value =  document.getElementById(this.id).value;

                    console.log(getID + "with a value of" + value);

                    if (value == ){
                        $(".div1").show();
                        $(".div2").hide();
                    }

                    else if (value == "2"){
                        $(".div1").hide();
                        $(".div2").show();
                    }

                });
```